# RichFaces 4 does not work in Payara 5 server

Tags: richfaces, payara

I'm trying to create a maven project with richfaces 4 to run on the payara server 5, but it always gives the following error:

```
Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.collect.MapMaker.makeComputingMap(Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap; from class org.richfaces.resource.ResourceLibraryFactoryImpl]]
```

Below are the libraries that maven downloaded:

```
richfaces-components-ui-4.0.0.Final.jar
richfaces-components-api-4.0.0.Final.jar
richfaces-core-api-4.0.0.Final.jar
richfaces-core-impl-4.0.0.Final.jar
cssparser-0.9.5.jar
sac-1.3.jar
guava-r08.jar
```

Comment: Did you try to update to RIchFaces `4.5`? Are you manually adding `guava` to your project in your `pom.xml`? This isse might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319981/how-to-use-google-guice-with-richfaces-4-3-7

Comment: If you're upgrading to RF 4 you should definitely use a newer version than 4.0.0; other than that the issue seems to be simply in resolving dependencies

Comment: My guess is that you have conflictIng Guava dependencies? The topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54058695 covers how you can resolve these dependency issues.